# Audio not working despite having installed audio driver (Lenovo R61)

Tags: windows-xp, audio, thinkpad

The computer is running Windows XP and I got the Audio driver installed, but for some reason I can't get audio.

I don't think it's a hardware problem since it had audio at one point before (that was before I redid the OS).

What steps can I do to fix this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is usually a HD audio driver(UAA High Definition Audio) that is needed in addition to the drivers from the vendoer.  My T61 needed the HD driver and then the driver from Lenovo.

Did you get the driver here? [R61 Audio](http://www-307.ibm.com/pc/support/site.wss/document.do?lndocid=MIGR-67816) Or a similar Lenovo site?  Also look here [UAA Driver](http://www-307.ibm.com/pc/support/site.wss/document.do?lndocid=migr-68153)  I have had a hard time finding this sometimes. Searching for UAA High Definition Audio has usually got me there.

Comment: Will try this when I get home but it sounds right.